# How do I use the /kill command to ONLY kill mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a Redstone Power loop that connects to a Command Block that is set to kill all entities except for myself (/kill @e[type=!Player]), because I'm building a creative map, but don't want slimes all over the place. Problem is if I want to place an Item Frame than the Command Block kills it.

So, is there anyway to exclude items from getting deleted, or make it so it will only target mobs?

Comment: @Unionhawk How do I use that for killing mobs though?

Comment: @Unionhawk I'm not seeing how that is supposed to kill entities. As far as I can tell that only selects players, and nothing else...

Comment: You'd use that selector you have set up (select whatever entities you want to exclude) in the context of a `/kill` command, so `/kill @e[score_selectMe_min=1]`.

Comment: @Unionhawk That doesn't seem to do what I want it to do. I can't do [code]/kill @e[!Player, !ItemFrame][/code]. I'm not even sure what that Score thing the other guy is talking about is meant to do.

Comment: @Unionhawk Yes, but I don't even understand what the code is doing, or how I'm supposed to apply it to what I want to do. Reading =/= understanding.

Comment: Referring to the question by @Unionhawk, you wanna kill all slimes and horses, for example, you can give all the slimes and horses a `selectMe` score of 1. Then use the method in the question to give all non slimes and horses a score of 0. You can then use the last command in the answer of the question to kill all the entities with score of 1, aka all slimes and horses.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 I understand now, but there are many different things that spawn that I don't want to. It'd be easier if there were a catch all way, and then just to be able to add exclusions from there.

Comment: @KernelPanic what entities do you not want to be killed?

Comment: Retracting my vote. It's related, but not a dupe.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 All mobs, and drops basically.

Comment: Actually you can first give all entities a score of 1, then changing the score of entities you don't want to be killed to 0. Is it easier?

Comment: @KernelPanic how about entities that you want to kill?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 I think giving all entities a score of 1, and then white listing the rest with 0 would work the easiest. How would I do that in code? Also can I chain multiple commands from one commend block?

Comment: If the number of types of entities that you want to kill is lower than that of you don't want to kill, then you can patiently set a score of 1 for those you want to kill and 0 for those you don't. If it is the other way around, then you can set 0 for all then change the score of entities you want to kill to 1. It may be much easier than just selecting a lot one by one.

Comment: @KernelPanic you cannot use 2 commands in one single command block. For the code, I will post that as an answer.

Comment: I feel like this is a duplicate...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simplest way to handle this is with a gamerule. If you don't want any mobs bothering you in your creative world, just turn off spawns with `/gamerule doMobSpawning false`. No mobs will spawn, which will allow you to have a quiet creative world, free from cows, pigs, sheep, chickens, slimes, etc, while also allowing yourself to do science on mobs at will. Mobs will spawn only when you want them to.

If you're really committed to the idea of doing this with `/kill`, however, you can do this one of two ways. You can set up individual command blocks to kill each type of mob, which might be a small set of command blocks if your main problem is slimes.

Alternatively, you can use the methods described in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/178846/20306) to select exceptions. It uses a scoreboard to set a score for all entities to 1, and simultaneously sets the score of all exceptions to 0. From there, you can select the set of all mobs excluding any exceptions you want with `@e[score_select_min=1]`.

The simplest and most flexible way to keep slimes from bothering you though is to turn off mob spawning altogether.

Comment: Does the /gamerule doMobSpawning false persist when reloading the save?

Comment: @KernelPanic Yes, gamerules are stored in level.dat.

Comment: *claps* Since when did you start typing this ;-;

Answer (score 19):

All you have to do is `/kill @e[type=YourMob]`

If you want to kill all mobs except yourself do:

1.12: `/kill @e[type=!Player]`

1.13: `/kill @e[type=!minecraft:player]`

Comment: `/kill @e[type=Creeper]` worked for me, thanks

Comment: @TechnikEmpire what did he lose?

Comment: @ElliotA. Somehow, every block he placed himself and every mob he placed.

Comment: Careful with this command,the `type=!Player` version deleted all blocks and mobs manually placed by users. I think it was forge 1.7.10 that this happened in.

Comment: OH!!!  All mobs = all player placed mobs also.  As for blocks most modded blocks are also entities and would get killed.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem in my world - how I resolved it was hooking up several command blocks to a hopper clock:

[image]

Each command block contains a command to kill a certain enemy type:

`/kill @e[type=Slime,r=60]`

I only need to worry about zombies, zombie villagers, creepers, skeletons, endermen, spiders, and witches; so I only have 7 command blocks hooked up here. You're welcome to hook up as many more as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

You can do /kill @e[type=Slime]
And you can do /gamerule doMobLoot false so they wont drop anything

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that hard, but you don't actually need a Command Loop to get rid of the mobs. Simply do `/gamerule doMobSpawning false` and it will resolve it. After that, the only mobs that can still spawn are the ones spawned by you.

With Command Blocks takes more time to do because have to do 2 commands.

First, do this command: `/gamerule doEntityDrops false` this command stops mobs from dropping items, then on the Command Block, set the command: `/kill @e[type=mob]`.

This is what I know, and I hope I helped you.

Good luck with your map, hope to see it done and play it soon!