# How can I test my command block contraptions for multiplayer compatibiltiy?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I like making command block contraptions.  Occasionally, I make a contraption that I want to use on a multiplayer server (or offer to server operators), but I don't know of a way to test that it'll actually work.

I don't run a server that I can test on, nor do I want to have to get friends/family on this non-existent server in order to do tests and debugging.  I also don't have op privileges on another server where I could do these tests (nor would I want to since it could disrupt the server).  Finally, I only own one Minecraft account, and I'm not really interested in buying a second account just for the purposes of testing command blocks.

So given that, what's the best way for me to perform my testing and debugging?  Is there a simple (and legitimate) way for me to add one or more players that I can control to my otherwise single player command block world?

Comment: Try them on yourself and use specific commands with coords and radius so you would not target unwanted players far away

Comment: It really isn't that hard to run a localhost server - just need java and the server jar. It would require owning multiple accounts though (for multiple clients) unless you're willing to use a cracked client on your own local server (which is a valid option).

Comment: @BRHSM: "I also don't have op privileges on another server where I could do these tests". Also, enforcing a radius on every command is at the very least impractical, and sometimes impossible.

Comment: @DaboRoss: The issue isn't running the server, the issue is that there's only one player (me) on that server.

Comment: Use two computers?

Comment: @PythonMaster: Doesn't really solve the actual problem.  Also, it's not hard to run more than one instance of Minecraft on a single computer.

Comment: The only solution I'd have then is to run an offline mode (cracked) client for a second player, or to buy a second account. There are bots which can cannot to servers but you can't control them.

Comment: Not sure if trial versions can enter LAN worlds. If they can, that's the solution: Use a trial account besides your normal account. Trial accounts are free.

Comment: @EgorHans It would be a bit of a hassle to register a new trial account basically each time I want to test something, but if it works, it might be worth it.

Answer (score 9):

What you could do to make your testing as real as possible is target entities with the `@e` selector in replacement of real players, and try testing your command blocks with entities like villagers.

For an example if you were trying to `tp` a player with `/tp @p (Coordinates)`  You could replace `@p or @a` with `@e` to teleport entities.

`@e` should be effective for most contraptions involving players.

Note:   This is how I test my contraptions unless I'm with a friend.

Comment: This is a good idea, but sometimes I need two or more players that are under direct control.  For instance, clearing items from an inventory.  Two actual players need to be present for testing, and I don't want to have to bug a friend to do debugging.

Comment: For replacing `@p`, don't use `@e` without extras. Use `@e[c=1]`, because that targets only the nearest entity, like `@p` targets only the nearest player.  For simulating `@a`, which targets all players, `@e` without a `c` condition, which targets all entities, works fine though.

Comment: As of the issue, you can always use entities with inventory. Say, a chest minecart. Or do you want to test commands that are actually unusable on entities other than players, like playing sounds?

Answer (score 0):

Way #1:

Open the Minecraft launcher 2x. Then log in on one of them into your account, in the other log into a 2nd account: Your friends, let's say. Just get the login info out of him somehow. Then launch bpoth Minecrafts

---

Way #2:

Try using for example a Pigman as a Player:

instead of @p will be @e[*scoreboard-value*, c=1]

Instead of *scoreboard-value* do:

First, create a dummy scoreboard objective:

> /scoreboard objectives add selectMe dummy

Then, on a fast redstone clock, give all entities a selectMe score of 0:

> /scoreboard players set @e selectMe 0

Give all players and items a selectMe score of 1 with these two command blocks:

> /scoreboard players set @e[type=Player] selectMe 1
>
> /scoreboard players set @e[type=Pigman] selectMe 1

Now, you can select them by targeting the closest entity that has a selectMe score of 1:

@e[score_selectMe_min=1,c=1]

scoreboard source [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166679/how-do-i-select-two-types-of-entities-in-minecraft-with-the-type-selector).

Comment: See my comment on @Jason_'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the item aspect, maybe use an entity with accessible items, like a donkey or chest minecart. You will be able to apply inventory changes and see what they do to the inventory. For things like armor or shields being visible, use a zombie, skeleton, or villager, if you are not willing to test on yourself.

If you have an old computer and a second Minecraft account, then you could use that.

Comment: For the second point, he explicitly said the latter is not the case. And the first point on its own could right as well be a comment on the topmost answer. Like the one I added before I saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a demo account to open LAN world, and your account log in