# How to tag two Players in one /testfor command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm searching how to tag two Players using one `/testfor` command. I'm actually using this command which works for one person :

```
/testfor @a[name=!<pseudo>,r=15]
```

But it doesn't work for two Players. Is it possible?

Comment: So, because I want command blockers in general to better command blockers, I have to ask: why are you using `testfor`?  Are you just using it as an example in this question, since it's an easy way of presenting your target selector, or some other reason?  I only ask because `testfor` is only useful in a limited number of cases when compared to other options.  I urge you to consider the problem more deeply, and think about which command is truly right for the job.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm using `testfor` because i'm creating a secured bank and I needed only two person which can enter in (the bank owner, and me the admin of the server).

Comment: Okay, in that case `testfor` probably isn't the right tool for the job.  I would just use the scoreboard (probably tags) and a selector to do this to teleport anyone that isn't tagged out of the bank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a dummy scoreboard objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add selectMe dummy
```

Then, add 2 players to the "selectMe":

```
/scoreboard players set @e[name=Name1] selectMe 1  
/scoreboard players set @e[name=Name2] selectMe 1
```

Now you can enter your command:

```
/testfor @a[score_selectMe_min=1,r=15]
```

or you can use this for an opposite effect:

```
/testfor @a[score_selectMe=0,r=15]
```

Help gotten from [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166679/how-do-i-select-two-types-of-entities-in-minecraft-with-the-type-selector)

Comment: There is no `score_name_max` parameter. The parameter you want is simply `score_name`. And that still won't work if players do not have a score prior (as they are not automatically tracked with a score of 0), meaning you'd need to set scores to 0 first.

Comment: Personally, I'd use scoreboard tags instead of actual scores.  They're designed for exactly this type of thing.

Comment: For future reference: Code formatting works better for Minecraft commands than block quotes.