# Command Block /execute at all UNnamed mobs of same type

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have various named Zombies. I want to do something with all OTHER Zombies.

`/execute @e[name=Zombie] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~`

Above does not seem to work. Any way to target Zombies that have no CustomName?

Comment: Oops, it was something else. Everything works perfectly now...

Comment: if you managed to fix it, I recommend that you post your fix as an answer. This is because someone else might run in the same issues as you, and as stack (and arqade) is an QA site, we answer also to help other users who might run in the same issue.

Comment: Howdoyoudothis howdoyoudothis? Please post it as answer, it is a pretty interesting goal.

Answer (score 1):

## 1.13 Update

You can use the `unless` subcommand of `/execute` to execute as all zombies that don't have the custom name:

```
execute
  as @e[type=zombie]
  unless data entity @s CustomName
run ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a scoreboard objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add selectMe dummy
```

Then add all your Zombies:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[name=Name1] selectMe 1  
/scoreboard players set @e[name=Name2] selectMe 1  
/scoreboard players set @e[name=Name3] selectMe 1
```

Now, you can execute your command:

```
/execute @e[score_selectMe=0] ~ ~ ~ summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~
```

For more info, click [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261634/how-to-tag-two-players-in-one-testfor-command/261639#261639).

Answer (score -3):

```
/execute @e[name=Unknown,type=Zombie] ~ ~ ~ /say hi
```

This command should work

Comment: It will not. "Unknown" is not the default name for zombies, it's just "Zombie". The OP's command was already in working order.

Comment: also if this would work how would you be able to test it if you make it say hi...