# How to /testfor a player's gamemode

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've recently had some difficulties finishing a system; in fact, I need to `/testfor` myself if I'm on spectator mode or another gamemode. Because I didn't know what to write, I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
/testfor Kimatuy {gamemode:3}
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Try this: `/testfor @p[name=Kimatuy, m=3]`

Comment: If anytimothy's answer solved it, you should hit the check mark :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of testing for a gamemode NBT tag, why don't you use the gamemode selector instead?

```
/execute if entity @a[gamemode=adventure]
```

If you want to mark players, you can use a `/scoreboard` command with the selectors set to `@a[gamemode=adventure]`.

---

Before 1.13, it is `/testfor @a[m=2]`, but as of 1.13, `m` was renamed to `gamemode`, `/testfor` was renamed to `/execute if entity`, and the argument is now the name of the mode.

Props to [@ppperry](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/185203/ppperry) for notifying me of this.

Comment: `m` was renamed to `gamemode` in 1.13

Comment: @ppperry Submit a suggested edit or create a new answer so that you can receive credit.

Comment: May I point out that your answer before the edit was testing for players in spectator mode, but your edit used adventure mode?

Comment: Also, /testfor no longer exists in 1.13; it was merged into /execute as `/execute if entity [selector]`

Answer (score 5):

To complete what aytimothy said, `@a[m=M] targets **all** Players with gamemode M:

`0` for Survival, `1` for Creative, `2` for Adventure, `3` for Spectator. 
For targeting Players that are, fer example, in gamemode 0 **or** 2, use scoreboards (vis [my answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261634/how-to-tag-two-players-in-one-testfor-command/261639#261639)):

First, create a dummy scoreboard objective:

```
/scoreboard objectives add gameM dummy
```

Then, add all Players with gamemode Survival and Adventure to the "selectMe":

```
/scoreboard players set @e[m=0] gameM 1  
/scoreboard players set @e[m=2] gameM 1
```

Now you can enter your command:

```
/testfor @a[score_gameM_min=1,r=15]
```

Comment: tags are better than scoreboards for this.

Comment: @RudolfJelínek "Tags" are a new feature added in 1.9 to add a label to a target without the use of objectives. It's much more efficient both internally and with command mechanisms where you need to target an entity based on a true/false condition.