# Is there a way to make a visible health bar for mobs other than ender dragons and withers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to create other mobs that have health bars like the ones you see when fighting withers or the ender dragon; or like name tags that have health displayed. I want it to work for Minecraft 1.11.2. I have found this and similar but I have run into the following problems:

1. The commands are out of date, all I can find is commands in 1.8,
2. Most of them are mods and plug-ins, and
3. The process descriptions for multiple commands are unclear and also out of date.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I wouldn't be asking this question if I hadn't had any knowledge of what I was doing, @Frank . I am also asking this because I know people who would like to have the answer to this question as well. If you need me to clarify the question than here it is: Is there a way to to make a health meter for monsters other than just withers and ender dragons. I prefer to use commands instead of mods for obvious reasons. I am running Minecraft 1.11.2.

Comment: I'm not asking you to clarify your question; I'm asking you to show what work you've put in to solve this. If you haven't done anything, you're going to have a rough reception here. We expect askers to at least make an attempt to solve their problem. Remember, we're all volunteers here, so respect our time.

Comment: @Frank I fixed the description

Comment: That's a start. It'd be better if you had actual commands you had tried, as well.

Comment: There are 2 main topics I was able to identify on your problem.
Gamplay and Game Dev. I suggest that everything related to Game Dev (Mod and Mob creator, to be posted on the Game Dev site from stackexchange).

You told that you want your 3 points solved, but they are not questions. As far as I can tell you need an updated command list, and the code to show the life of the mobs:` http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands (4 days ago) `


As @Frank said: Be more objective: `I want to do this`  - `I tried this but not worked` - `Is there any other way to do it?`
Same goes for the game dev

Comment: Curious, why did you accept an answer and then place a bounty?  You should unaccept the other one if you do not like it and accept the one you found most useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Have you tried making it yourself?

What you can try doing is:

1. Assign a scoreboard value based on a mob's health.

> *NB: You cannot use the `health` criteria on entities. Only players.*
>  `/scoreboard objectives add healthbar dummy`

2. Test for mob healths and assign them a score based on their current health in a repeater command block.

> `/scoreboard players set @e healthbar __ {Health:__s}`
>  Replace `__` with a health value, and repeat from 1 (half a heart) to 100 (max health of golems).
>  You should have a long row of command blocks just doing this if you're doing it correctly.

3. Give mob names based on their health. Here's two unicode symbols that represent hearts: `♥♡`, every tick after #2 happens.

> If you know what you are doing, you can [find your heart symbols in here](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf).
>  `/entitydata @e[score_healthbar_min=20,score_healthbar=20] {CustomName:"♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥"}`
>  `/entitydata @e[score_healthbar_min=18,score_healthbar=19] {CustomName:"♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡"}`
>  `/entitydata @e[score_healthbar_min=16,score_healthbar=17] {CustomName:"♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡"}`
>  `/entitydata @e[score_healthbar_min=14,score_healthbar=15] {CustomName:"♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♡♡♡"}`
>  and so on... Of course, you could just do plain numbers:
>  `/entitydata @e[score_healthbar_min=20,score_healthbar=20] {CustomName:"♥ 20"}`
>  `/entitydata @e[score_healthbar_min=19,score_healthbar=19] {CustomName:"♥ 19"}`
>  `/entitydata @e[score_healthbar_min=18,score_healthbar=18] {CustomName:"♥ 18"}`
>  `/entitydata @e[score_healthbar_min=17,score_healthbar=17] {CustomName:"♥ 17"}`
>  or, if you cannot use Unicode:
>  `/entitydata @e[score_healthbar_min=20,score_healthbar=20] {CustomName:"Health: 20"}`
>  `/entitydata @e[score_healthbar_min=19,score_healthbar=19] {CustomName:"Health: 19"}`
>  `/entitydata @e[score_healthbar_min=18,score_healthbar=18] {CustomName:"Health: 18"}`
>  `/entitydata @e[score_healthbar_min=17,score_healthbar=17] {CustomName:"Health: 17"}`

If you know what you're doing, you should have a long chain of about about 150 chain command blocks and a repeat command block and mobs should have health bar as their custom name. Less, if you only only want to test a smaller health range, or put all mobs with more than 20 health as "`20+`" or any other optimisation changes, etc.

The downsides to this system however, is **ALL NAMETAG NAMES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN**.
A workaround would be to put `@e[type=MOBNAME]`, but that would multiply the number of commands you have to create by the number of mobs you want to track.

> Or, you could look at this [answer on how to tag specific mob types](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/178846/75275) and then instead of the above paragraph, just edit your health testing commands to only test selected mobs. Of course, you would need a few more extra command blocks to do your marking of mobs that should have their health tracked and displayed and the command blocks handling steps 2 and 3 should have a selector to filter for those mobs too.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for. But before I award, you need to specify where or how you can obtain the unicode "heart" symbols.

Comment: Have even made the effort to copy-paste them from this page or doing a little googling? Here's the [Unicode charts for block U+2700](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2700.pdf)?