# Is there anyway to show a mobs health above their head (1.17, Java) with only command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a dungeon style game, and I want the mobs to have their health above their head, and update when they heal or get hurt. Is there anyway to do this with just command blocks/commands. Because all of the answers that I've found are either mods, or don't work.

Comment: I found something similar that has been asked before.
This might answer your question:
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/306479/189958

Comment: you could try doing scoreboard commands, one for each mob (but that means you'll have to have a fixed amount of mobs) and put them as "show under name" instead of the sidebar

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work.

```
scoreboard objectives add Hp health

scoreboard objectives setdisplay belowName Hp

execute as @e[type=!player] at @s run scoreboard players add @s 0

scoreboard players add @a Health 0
```

'hp' is the scoreboard name

'health' links health of the entity to the scoreboard

'scoreboard objectives setdisplay belowName Hp' makes the hp visible above the name or head

'execute as @e[type=!player] at @s run scoreboard players add @s 0' adds every entity but players to the scoreboard. meaning their health starts being tracked by the scoreboard

'scoreboard players add @a Health 0' adds players to the scoreboard